# $\begin{bmatrix}6&a\\b&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2\\0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}4\\-10\end{bmatrix}$ Find $a$ and $b$

Tags: matrices

If:

$$\begin{bmatrix}6&a\\b&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2\\0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}4\\-10\end{bmatrix}$$

and:

$$\begin{bmatrix}6&a\\b&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0\\3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}6\\3\end{bmatrix}$$

find the values of $a$ and $b$.

I multiplied out the left hand side of the first expression to get:

$$12 = 4  ;2b =-10$$
and then the second expression to get:
$$3a=6;3=3$$
From this I got: $a=2$ and $b=-5$, which is also the answer in the back of my book.

But why did I get 12=4 ?

And how come when I sub the values for $a$ and $b$ back into the original expressions they don't equate ?

Comment: Maybe you are working modulo 8? Or there is a mistake in the exercise...

Comment: 12=4 seems dubious.  Perhaps there is a typo?

Comment: You got that because the book's authors made a mistake. As you observe, substituting back in shows that the values found do not constitute a solution to the problem.